# How do I display my sub-menu items on the same line?

Tags: css, wordpress

Since this is a CSS question, I'm going to post it here. I'm using the twenty twelve wordpress theme and at the moment my sub menu items each display on a separate line.

How do I display all 4 menu items on the same line?

Comment: try using float: left; in css

Answer (score 0):

Try this css rules for your class:

```
 .sub-menu{
        display:inline-block;
        float:left;
    }
```